# User Access Control in HomeKit & avoiding limitations

Tags: ios, ios9, ios10, homekit, ios-homekit

I'm just starting to get into HomeKit, and I have a couple of questions about it -

1) In the current version of HomeKit, only the homeowner can create action sets for his/her home, whereas the guests or other members of the household can only execute the given action sets. Is it actually possible to surpass this limitation or does HomeKit block this on OS-Level? So in particular I mean: is it possible to let the guests / non-homeowners also create action sets?

2) Can you in-code set certain users as Home Owners? (This means, is it possible to have multiple home owners for one home?)

3) Can non-home owners set triggers for action sets or edit existing action sets?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes if you give users administrative access via home the app. This can be done after you invited them to your home.

2) Yes you are allowed to have multiple admins per home, again configurable by the home app.

3) Non admins ( non home owners )  are not allowed to add/remove scenes or accessories. They are however allowed to control them ie turn light on or off.

Comment: where exactly can you define the amount of system admins in the home app? Because on the Apple HomeKit Framework Page I only read there is one admin per home - A link or anything of the sorts would be nice!

Comment: See this article specifically,  'Allow remote access and edit permissions for users'. https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT207057  Toggling the allow editing gives a user an admin privileges.

Comment: Thank you so much! That helps me out a LOT. One question: Does this only work if you have a Home Hub set up or can you toggle these permissions without having a Home Hub, just through your Iphone?